# Mysql query: Select with joining first or default

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. `Persons` and `Images`.

One person may have many images.
I want to select a person with his primary image **BUT(!)**, if none of the images marked as `isPrimary=1` bring the first one.
Only one or less images may be `isPrimary=1`

```
SELECT
  *,
  (
    SELECT id 
    FROM Image 
    WHERES personId=r.id AND isPrimary=1  
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS primaryImageId
FROM Persons r 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I did it with subselect, join is also good...
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT r.*,
       (SELECT i.id
        FROM Image i
        WHERES i.personId = r.id 
        ORDER BY i.isPrimary DESC, i.id ASC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS primaryImageId
FROM Persons r
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This orders the images, with the primary one first -- and then takes the first image.

You should learn to qualify *all* column references -- this is especially important when using correlated subqueries.  I assume that the alias `r` makes sense on the `persons` table in your native language.  Otherwise, use something sensible such as `p`.

Comment: Perfect, will be accepted. BTW, I didnt use the col reference to simplify it here. Thanks